# xcodebuild not working with pods and multiple targets

Tags: xcode, cocoapods, xcodebuild

I am trying to add CocoaPods to an existing project with multiple targets. My podfile looks like

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '8.0'

link_with 'Target 1', 'Target 2', 'Target 2', 'Target 2'
pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 2.0'
```

I am trying to build using a script that has the following command

```
xcodebuild archive -project "${PROJ_NAME}.xcodeproj" -scheme ${SCHEME_NAME} -configuration ${CONFIGURATION}
```

When I compile I get an error:

```
ld: library not found for -lPods-AFNetworking
```

This is strange because the targets archive using the menu Product > Archive in Xcode.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like you're not building the generated `xcworkspace` file here. Switch to that in your command and you should be fine.